# Safe exam browser not working with moodle

Tags: moodle

I've installed SEB (`Safe Exam Browser` V 2.0) with which I conduct an exam in their special browser. I've installed the plugin in `moodle Ver 2.8` and for every test to be conducted through `Safe exam browser` I have applied the special browser key which is to be placed in an extra attempt section. But still I'm facing difficulty while taking tests through the `Safe exam Browser`, it is displaying `You must use an approved version of Safe Exam Browser to attempt this test.`

Kindly help me on this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First enable ***Safe Exam Browser*** in Experimental Settings (`Site Admin > Development > Experimental > Experimental Settings > Enable SEB`)

After that, update in Authenticated Users role by enabling ***Safe Exam Browser*** in it(`Site Admin > Users > Permissions > Define Roles > Authenticated user > Exempt from Safe Exam Browser check`).

Vardhan :)